# Adding Custom Font android using lib

Tags: java, android, xml

I am using android custom font lib Calligraphy https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy.

But there is no effect on textview. I am using the below code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(new CalligraphyContextWrapper(newBase));
    }
}
```

In XML:

```
<TextView
        tools:context=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Touch Listner"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:fontPath="fonts/gotham-book.ttf" />
```

In attrs:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="fontPath" format="string"/>
</resources>
```

In assets/font/gotham-book.ttf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the class that extends Application, now and the following code in it. and declare it in manifest under application tag.

```
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()
    );
```

Comment: It took me 1 hour to figure out that I need to place fonts under "assets/fonts/...." but while giving path I have to skip "assets" folder from font-path.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the namespace from the `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    tools:context=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Touch Listner"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    fontPath="fonts/gotham-book.ttf" />
```

(Change `app:fontPath` to `fontPath`)

Annoyingly we can't resolve the auto-res namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Create the class that extends `Application`.
Something like that:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/DINNextLTPro-Regular.otf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );
    }

}
```

The next thing we need to do is to open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file of our application and add a reference to `MyApplication` in the `android:name` attribute of the application tag, so in the end the manifest file will look similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="it.sbsmobile.golife"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.example.MyApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".Profile1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also, the instructions at https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy say to inject into the context, by overriding a method in the **activity** as follows:

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Source: [LINK](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Why extend Application class? [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-extend-an-application-class)

Answer (score 2):

1) Download and copy your font (yourfont.ttf) file in the assets folder of your project

2) In your Activity/Fragment use the following code to load the font

```
 Typeface yourfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
```

3) Find your TextView(or any other view on which you want to set this font) and use the setTypeface method of the View.
eg.

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.exampletextview);
textview1.setTypeface(yourfont);
```

This of course comes with a drawback, that if there are a lot of views you want to apply the font to you would have manually setTypeface for each of the view. In that case you can make a custom view by extending the Textview class. Something like the code below :

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/yourfont.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);

}
```

}

and use this in xml as `<com.yourpackagename.MyTextView />`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Here, You need to do two things.

Firstly,in xml, add two lines (as shown in below) in root of layout

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
```

And last, in Activity class,

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

Yooooo, it's done !! Simple

[Example please check https://i.stack.imgur.com/F87JE.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F87JE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've used TypefaceTextView lib to obtain the results you want. Please, take a look at (https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-typeface-textview).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple [EasyFonts](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2044) third party library to set variety of custom font to your `TextView`. By using this library you should not have to worry about downloading and adding fonts into the assets/fonts folder. Also about Typeface object creation.

Provided font faces. Which might you would like to use.

- Roboto
- Droid Serif
- Droid Robot
- Freedom
- Fun Raiser
- Android Nation
- Green Avocado
- Recognition

Simply:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoThin(this));
```