# Can't initialize quickblox framework in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, quickblox

I use these lines of codes to initialize quickblox framework in activity according to quickblox documentation

```
QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(), APP_ID, AUTH_KEY, AUTH_SECRET);
QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
```

but when i use the same code in fragment replacing getApplicationContext() with getActivity() it stops execution on that line, i have also tried getActivity().getApplicationContext and getActivity().getBaseContext() but not wokring for me

Comment: why dont you initialize this in application class or base activity class ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-extend-an-application-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write these line of code In your Application class. Take a reference from [Here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/blob/master/sample-core/src/main/java/com/quickblox/sample/core/CoreApp.java)

. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: i have created a application class and initialize these lines of code but how do i make this class to run when application is launched

Comment: @user7661245 In your menifest class **<application
        android:name=".activities.MyApplication"...**. You can replace **MyApplication** with your Application class name.