# How to avoid subclassing Android.App.Application

Tags: c#, android, database, xamarin, android-context

In the past I've subclassed `Application` to maintain an active database connection for the application.  However, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18003448/1399272) `Application` runs in the UI thread, which makes me think I should definitely not use it for database access.  Furthermore, according to the [Xamarin `Application` docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Application/) (and those of Android proper):

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way. If your singleton needs a global context (for example to register broadcast receivers), the function to retrieve it can be given a [`Context`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Context/) which internally uses [`Context.ApplicationContext`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.Context.ApplicationContext/) when first constructing the singleton.

I think I understand the `Context` to be something I can use to maintain some sort of static access to application resources, but there are no examples in the docs and I've not encountered this situation before.  Would anyone be able to explain the above note and relate how they have used `Context` to maintain application resources (unless I'm completely missing the point)?  Links to or direct examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I've found the droid answer I'm looking for.

Dave Smith has provided a [simple example](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) of a "static singleton" as referenced in the doc notes above:

```
public class CustomManager {
    private static CustomManager sInstance;

    public static CustomManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            //Always pass in the Application Context
            sInstance = new CustomManager(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private Context mContext;

    private CustomManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

The `Context` itself does not contribute to the longevity of the `CustomManager` - its existence is simply owing to the nature of a static singleton itself.  The `Context` as provided by `context.getApplicationContext()` (Xamarin  `Context.ApplicationContext`) is simply a means of accessing the application `Context` if it is needed by the singleton.

That being said, as elaborated by [this SO question and its top two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826905/singletons-vs-application-context-in-android), the real question is not so much if, but how do you want your global application data to be a singleton - as an extension of the framework-supplied `Application` singleton, or as an additional, separate singleton you create which may or may not make use of the former.

For my part, I think I am content with simply subclassing the `Application` after all.  It intuitively makes more sense to store application data in some variant of the `Application` class.  Furthermore, I have certain OOP misgivings about creating singletons in general, so I feel safer using the one already existing than making my own.  This singleton is managed by the framework, so while that does not guarantee safety from the typical woes of what essentially boils down to a global variable (boo hiss), at least it is a little safer than rolling my own.

P.S. - re: the using the `Application` which runs in the UI thread, it seems using a static singleton does not do me any extra favors - again, since that's all using `Application` amounts to anyway.  I think I will probably follow the advice offered [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and make use of `AsyncTask`s for processor-heavy operations.