# preserving Singleton DB data on rotation Without using ContentProvider (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, singleton

How do you preserve **singleton** database data in an activity after a screen rotation **without** using Content Provider or loaders?

This was an interview question I got stumped on.

ContentProvider with cursor loader was my first thought, but they said they didn't want that. Then I thought of saving the cursor returned from the singleton DB's query method, but I couldn't "put" a cursor in the out bundle in OnSavedInstance, so I have no idea.

I also asked them "isn't using a singleton database discouraged?" to which they said "yes, but this is just for interview purposes."

Maybe this can help someone in the future who encounters this question.

Comment: "In an activity" sounds like I'm not allowed to pass all the stuff to the application class (which will not be destroyed on screen rotation). So I'd use a [retained Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject)

Comment: Retained fragment makes a lot of sense, thanks. By "passing to the application class", do you mean having something like "public static MyApplication varName" in MainActivity that I store info in?

(You could answer my question and I'll give you the green checkmark btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In an activity" sounds like I'm not allowed to pass all the stuff to the application class (which will not be destroyed on screen rotation). But just in case this is an option:

You write your own class which extends from `Application`. The official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) tells you how to do it but states that you basically don't need to. Having said that, this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-extend-an-application-class) is a collection of possible exceptions from the rule.

In the `Activity`, you access it like this:

```
MyApplication app = (MyApplication)getApplication();
```

But personally I'd keep data for one `Activity` not in the `Application` class but inside a retained `Fragment`. They survive configuration changes but keep in mind that they are not part of the back stack. So if you have a savedInstanceState != null, the  retained `Fragment` may nevertheless have been recreated in its initial state e.g. if the app has been paused for a while.

The guide on [Handling Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject) shows how to use retained `Fragment`s

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fragments` and use `Fragment#setRetainInstance(true)` for that. And all the data should be saved across configuration changes. Note that a retained fragment is not visual its placed along your `Activity` or `Fragment` This might help you: https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html