# Why Do We Extend Application Class In Android

Tags: android

Why do we extend application class. Android apps run properly even without extending it.

Can anyone explain this scenario as why exactly do we extend it.

For Example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private static MyApp app;
    private ImageDownloaderComponent imageDownloaderComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        app = this;
        imageDownloaderComponent = DaggerImageDownloaderComponent.builder().imageDownloaderModule(new ImageDownloaderModule(this)).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Because it's the only singleton global instance of Context that can be freely used in most cases around the app  (except alert dialogs, anything involving inflation of support v4 widgets, and starting activities)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why to extend an Application class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-to-extend-an-application-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Android apps run properly even without extending it.

Android apps *can* run properly without extending it. They can run properly without extending `Activity`. You extend `Application` when it does something useful for you.

> Can anyone explain this scenario as why exactly do we extend it.

It is used for per-process initialization that should *always* happen, not just for certain activities or other components.

So, for example, you might initialize:

- Dependency injection (e.g., Dagger)
- Crash logging (e.g., ACRA)
- Diagnostic tools (e.g., LeakCanary, Stetho, Sonar)
- Global pools (e.g., `OkHttpClient`)

Ideally, you initialize as little as possible, simply because this initialization is performed on the main application thread every time your process is forked. But, it is often convenient for things that should be set up before any of your application logic is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination bro.. I really appreciate the way you did.. But I dont understand why do people downvote the question.. Questions will be important for people who have no idea about it..?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån the downvotes most likely happened because you duplicated an old question.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel Oh, Okay!!