# Start a thread once and only once

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have one singleton object on which I would exactly one thread executing while the app is running.

So far I have created the thread in `MainActiviy::onCreate`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     thread{myobject.run()}
   }
}
```

But contrary to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) where the arrow leading to `onCreate()` is *App process is killed*, it looks like `onCreate()` is called every time the app is restarted regardless of if being killed or if its threads were still running.
[image: flowchart]

```
object myobject{
   fun run(){
      while(true){
         do_stuff()
      }
   }
}
```

It is of course possible to acquire a lock to only start the thread once, but since there is a nice syntax in Kotlin for singleton objects, and this is a related (I assume very common) problem I came to believe there maybe could be a simple more elegant way for this.

Or is the preferred way to acquire a lock on the object?

Comment: I think you should start your thread in onCreate() of Application so there will be only one thread throughout the life of your app

Comment: That is what I am doing but `onCreate()` is called when the user leaves and returns to the app so I get multiple threads

Comment: You are doing this in onCreate of a activity I said do in onCreate of Application class 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002227/why-extend-the-android-application-class

Comment: Please write this as an answer!

Comment: Like this: https://medium.com/@balakrishnanpt/android-application-class-a8a1d64c82d1

Comment: I'm kinda busy now i will write an answer ASAP

Comment: Whenever you have time, if  you write this in an answer I will upvote and accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by starting the thread in OnCreate of your Application class. Make a class extending the Application class and add this class in your manifest

**MyApp.kt**

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
       thread{myobject.run()} //here
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<application 
   android:name=".com.yourpakage.MyApp"
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   ...>
```

Unlike the activity lifecycle Application's onCreate is called only once. So there will be only one thread throughout the life of your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntentService` and store the status on a `SharedPreference`.
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: So I should change myobject to a subclass of  `IntentService` and start it from the manifest?

Comment: Refer to this for some examples https://www.zoftino.com/android-intentservice-example