# My multidex is not resolving (it is still red)

Tags: android, firebase, android-multidex

My android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication is still red after all the steps. I am not able to resolve this. I'm following a course online but can't find the answer. Can I omit multidex?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ping"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ping">

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
          (this part is showing error)
        >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing androidX with Support libraries.

You should replace:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

with

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

and replace

```
android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
```

with

```
androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication
```

Comment: hi is it not possible to do it with implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'? as the course im using , my instructor uses the same version. and i havent migrated to androidx.

Comment: this `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2` entry in your gradle indicates that your project is already in androidX. So older support versions will cause conflicts. Don't worry there won't be any issue if you use androidX version, it is more stable and conflict free.

Comment: Also, if this solves your problem, please approve the answer.

Comment: sir so even if i follow a course that uses 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0, instead of adding this, i can add the androidx library and it will be fine?

Comment: thankyou sir now no errors as I changed multidex androidx version. i even updated androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2  to 1.2.0 hope thats okay? and is there any way you could help with my project sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an application class that extends MultiDexApplication

You need to have this **dependency for AndroidX**

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Or for the normal **support library**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Below is the code if you want it in **Kotlin**

```
class YourAppName : MultiDexApplication()
```

Or for **Java**

```
class YourAppName extends MultiDexApplication
```

And in your manifest file in the application tag

```
android:name:".YourAppName"
```

If you're thinking why to have an application class here is some reading you can do

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33315717/10752944

Comment: hi do you mean like this? package com.example.ping

import androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication

class ping: MultiDexApplication()

Comment: hi is there any way I can get your help for my uni project?  I just need an experts help.

Comment: yes @GayatriAnushka the same way you said in the first comment

Comment: that did not work, showed more errors and NDK unknown. so changed to the multidex androidx version

Comment: If you see the answer carefully, I have written in the first line itself that you need AndroidX version